# Plotting fit in gnuplot log($1):($2) defining xrange

Tags: plot, gnuplot, data-fitting

I have a question regarding plotting a exponential fit in `Gnuplot` and having the `y-axis` set in `logscale`. I am using *Gnuplot 4.6.3*.
I will present the few ways I have tried setting a range to fit in:

The function I want to fit on the data is **f(x)=a+b*x**

The first:

```
set log y
f(x)=a+b*x
fit [4:8] f(x) 'CT2A_OH_R_log.dat' using (log($1)):($2) via a,b
```

Resutls:

```
         Read 15 points
         Skipped 15 points outside range [x=4:8]
         No data to fit
         error during fit
```

The second:

```
fit f(x) 'CT2A_OH_R_log.dat' using (log($1)):($2) via a,b
```

Results:

```
Final set of parameters              Asymptotic Standard Error
a          =16.9858                  +/- 6.299          (37.08%)
b          =-8.43215                 +/- 3.502          (41.53%)
gnuplot> plot 'CT2A_OH_R_log.dat', f(x) via a,b
```

Obviously the fit is ridiculous but this is the only way I know of that actually gives me a fit. I know the problem most likely lies within the defining of the `xrange` when fitting but what else can I write there to fix this?

Below I will show image of my plot (f(x) is not showing as it is plotted in the negative area.)

Answer (score 1):

'cause a `logscale` of the y `axis` requires the logarithm of the y axis during the fit ;-)

```
fit [4:8] f(x) 'CT2A_OH_R_log.dat' u 1:(log($2)) via a,b
```

**NOTE**

If you want to use the logarithm based on 10, you have to use `log($2)/log(10)` or `log10($2)`.

Comment: Thanks! I overlooked such a stupid mistake! 
However, I did that now and I still get a strange fit: 

    gnuplot> fit [4:8] [0.1:60] f(x) 'CT2A_OH_R_log.dat' using 1:(log($2)) via a,b
    gnuplot> plot 'CT2A_OH_R_log.dat', f(x) via a,b

This time the fit is exponential like. 
I want to add a picture but I can not do this in comment section. So, please see the comment below: